# Multiple Restricted Words

Tags: validation, google-appsheet

In Appsheet's DATA VALIDITY (Valid If) expression, is there a way to put a  restriction on multiple words (needle) from a row (haystack) that is of type "text"? I know the following works:

NOT(CONTAINS([Comment],"value"))

However, is there an expression that would allow for the restriction of more than just one value? Like: "value1", "value2", "value3", "etc..." So, if the comment contains any of those values it would flag an "invalid value error".

The following works with Contains(), but it doesn't with NOT(Contains())

OR(CONTAINS([Comment], “value1” ),CONTAINS([Comment], “value2”),CONTAINS([Comment],“value3”))

Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer I was looking for:

```
NOT(OR(CONTAINS([Comment], "value"), contains([Comment],"value2"), contains([Comment],"value3"), contains([Comment],"value4"), contains([Comment],"value5")))
```

Although it would be nice to have a separate table to list the values ONCE and reference other tables to it. But this will do for now.